# Convert a series of arrays to a single list

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert series which has array within array to a list.
This is the series:

```
    0
0   [[136.26198653744652]]
1   [[595.1701354429704]]
2   [[106.31607570796812]]
3   [[579.6333400908089]]
4   [[402.1731384585597]]
5   [[380.381375557186]]
type(b1)
Out[130]: pandas.core.series.Series

b1[1]
Out[131]: array([[595.1701354429704]], dtype=object)
```

I have  tried tolist(),.values or to_numpy() etc. Nothing worked except the following

```
b1.explode().explode().tolist()
```

This is what I got.
    [136.26198653744652,
    595.1701354429704,
    106.31607570796812,
    579.6333400908089,
    402.1731384585597,
    380.381375557186]

To my understanding here explode does unboxing/unlisting like thing. I'm looking for some better solution here which helps to change the type of every element of a series and produce the result of b1.explode().explode().tolist().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 times flatten lists in `Series`:

```
L = [z for x in b1 for y in x for z in y]
print (L)
[136.26198653744652, 595.1701354429704, 106.31607570796812,
 579.6333400908089, 402.1731384585597, 380.381375557186]
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative, using [chain](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html)

```
data ={ 0 : [[[136.26198653744652]],   [[595.1701354429704]],   [[106.31607570796812]],   [[579.6333400908089]],   [[402.1731384585597]],   [[380.381375557186]]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

from itertools import chain
combine = chain.from_iterable

list(combine(combine(df[0])))

[136.26198653744652,
 595.1701354429704,
 106.31607570796812,
 579.6333400908089,
 402.1731384585597,
 380.381375557186]
```

Comment: Hi. Did the code fail? Something I’m missing. Downvoting is fine; however  I would love to get some feedback

Comment: Downvote was a mistake due to error in click. I tried to upvote again but I cannot since you need to resubmit the answer. Im so sorry.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback @Tamal